# Cig lighter blown fuse

Tags: honda, odyssey, power-outlet

In my 2001 Honda Odyssey the front ACC socket is blowing the fuse and now both sockets front and back don't work I checked fuse nine on both sides passenger and driver side and they're both good is there any other fuse I can check

Comment: Are the ACC sockets the only load on that fuse line?  Manuracturers are cunning when trying to economise on fuses, and even more cunning when designing wiring diagrams to 'hide' connections to other loads:)  (side note - why are auto wring diagrams so difficult to follow? :)

Comment: Check fuse 8 in the driver interior fuse block is good as well. That fuse is for the Accessory Socket Power Relay coil and is powered key on engine off or running. Does anything else not work? From the the way the wiring diagram looks if fuse 8 (Driver) or 9 (Passenger) blew, the radio shouldn't work nor should the cigarette lighter.